# Strichartz estimates

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, wave-equation

In the Blair, Smith and Sogge's paper  [Strichartz estimates for the wave equation on manifolds with boundary](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0294144909000080), the authors study integrability
estimates for solution of the following problem:

\begin{equation}
\partial_t^2 u(t,x)-\Delta_g u(t,x)=0, ~ u(0,x)=f(x),  ~ \partial_tu(0,x)=g(x)  \tag{1.1}
\end{equation}
where $\Delta_g$ denotes the Laplace–Beltrami operator on $(M,g)$ with $(M, g)$  a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n \geq 2$.

They establish the following result:

**Theorem 1.1.** Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary. Suppose $2<p\leq \infty$, $2 \leq q < \infty$ and $(p,q,\gamma)$ is a triple satisfying
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{q} + \frac{n}{q}= \frac{n}{2}-\gamma \hspace{ 2cm}\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{p}+\frac{n-1}{q} \leq \frac{n-1}{2}, n \leq 4 \\
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{1}{2}, n \geq 4
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then we have the following estimates for solutions $u$ to (1.1) satisfying either Dirichlet or Neumann homogeneous boundary conditions
\begin{equation} \|u\|_{L^{p}([-T,T];L^q(M))}\leq C(\|f\|_{H^{\gamma}(M)}+\|g\|_{H^{\gamma-1}(M)})\end{equation}
with $C$ some constant depending on $M$ and $T$.

> **My question:** Does anyone know of any place that has a didactic proof (with details) of this result, showing the dependency of the constant $C$ on $T$ and $M$? Containing the prerequisites and tools necessary to understand the proof.
>
> The proof can be done in a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.